# create a folder and insert an index.php file with code in it

Tags: php, content-management-system, makefile, directory

I am developing a cms and want a user to create a folder and also insert an index.php file with some lines of code to be executed. This should be done from the control panel and every thing should be done using code.

Thanks

I have tried this code

```
if (!file_exists('folder_path')) {
    mkdir('folder_path');
}
```

However i have no idea whether i can create an index.php file and insert code into it
using fopen

```
$file_name = "index.php";
$create_file = fopen($file_name, "r");
```

Comment: :| what have you tried?

Comment: This should be done from the control panel and every thing should be done using code AND TRY

Answer (score 0):

First of all, of course you can, and there are several ways to do so. fopen() is one of them, but I am guessing that you would better off trying to utilize one of these:

```
file_put_contents( $filename, $data )
```

[Documentation link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

or, depending on your implementation of the CMS, I am guessing you may want to place a default starting template there, so simply

```
copy( $tempalte_file, $new_path )
```

[Documentation link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Finally, if you insist for some reason to use fopen, just use the (w)rite flag, which will attempt to create the file if it does not exist:

```
$handle = fopen( $filename, "w" );
```

[Documentation link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: After a look around I found an interesting solution [here][1]. I tried it out and boom i got it.

Comment: Your link did not come through in the comment

Comment: its [here] http://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete

Comment: I must say your method is also good if you are to look at file permissions wont the server need authentication for fopen

Comment: All methods will have problems if there are no write permissions for the process that runs php. Normally, unless you set it otherwise, you have write permissions.